# Memory too small on a partition

Tags: partitioning

My home partition is full, so you know at what kind of trouble can leads this. I have two partitions by 40 GB and I was wondering which would be the best method for transferring files or adding a path?

Comment: PLease clarify your question and add the result of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question for better answers.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  I have edited out your second question, feel free to ask a new question about it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your size of the given partition with [**gparted**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=gparted&op=).
It's a tool used for creating/editing the partitions. To install it, open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type:

`sudo apt-get install gparted`.

There you can extend your partitions.
Helpful link: [Geeks](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/)

Comment: I've tried Gparted and I have to un mount the home partition which is being used, so no dice. Any other suggestions?